# foreach in node issue on object id

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I don't know why this is happening.

I have one array which mongo objectId.

```
var all_id = [5e4e7b35fb122128dc7e71, 5e43eec5b627fe204cedde];

[...all_id].forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

I also use this one

```
all_id.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

> all_id.forEach is not a function

Output(get single char including [ **(bracket also)** )

```
[

5

e

4

e

7

b

3

5

f
```

want output like this

```
5e4e7b35fb122128dc7e71
5e43eec5b627fe204cedde
```

please help what can I do for resolving this

Comment: How do you get `all_id`? Post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to quote your strings.

```js
const all_id = ["5e4e7b35fb122128dc7e71", "5e43eec5b627fe204cedde"];

[...all_id].forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

This code produces the expected output in the snippet code runner.

If you are getting this over REST, then you may need to `JSON.parse` it:

```
   if (typeof all_id === 'string') {
     all_id = JSON.parse(all_id)
   }

    [...all_id].forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item);
    });
```

Comment: the quote is added but it removes automatically

Comment: What removes it?

Comment: thanks, bro but this is not quoted issue I send array through the postman so that problem has occurred

Comment: You don't have a reproducible problem in your question then. I solved the problem in your question, you notice. Your _actual_ problem is that you are operating on a string. I'll update it. You gotta give the context.

Comment: See if the JSON.parse does it for you.